# Django application does not properly load Twitter bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making a Django application and using Twitter bootstrap carousel template for making a my site. I am planning to provide the sign up and sign in feature to the users through Twitter boostrap 3 modal.

and When I test modal simple with my external templates (not included in Django). My Modal runs well.

Here is my Modal code

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
  <!-- calling sign up modal -->
          <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#signup"><b>Sign Up</b></a></li>
          <!-- calling sign up modal finished -->  
              <!-- sign up modal -->
              <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="signup">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                </div><!-- /.modal -->
          <!-- sign up modal finish -->
</ul>
```

Correct results
See image below

[image]

But when I run this modal from Django application templates. the modal loads but one grey transparent screen also loads over it and it makes the whole page disabled.

See image below[image]

What would be the problem

Comment: Is the html code returned by django is correect? What is the source code of the "wrong" page?

Comment: The error is 304 for that click I make for opening modal

Comment: thanks eran for the reply but I solved this issue by defining my modal code outside the ul tags, I put my modal code just after start of the body tag and it worked for me.

Comment: Now after fixing this my Dropdown menu on the same navbar not working and when I reverted the changes the dropdown still not working whereas outside my Django application both modal and dropdown menu are working perfectly.

Comment: fixed the dropdown menu problem by removing a line from the bottom of my header.html<br/>

 <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"/> <br/>

and now dropdown menu started working fine.

Comment: @ChitrankDixit - you should make your solution as an answer and accept it - perhaps helping people with a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by defining my modal code outside the ul tags, I put my modal code just after start of the body tag and it worked for me.

This is my code

```
<!-- Modal 1 -->
              <!-- define the sign up modal finished -->  
                  <!-- sign up modal -->
                  <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="signup">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">TrackLeech Sign Up</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <form class="navbar-form form-inline" align="left">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="username" class="form-control" style="width: 200px;"> 
                                <!-- Fb Login --> <div class="fb-login-button pull-right" data-width="400">Login with Facebook</div><!-- Add FB Button Here --> <br><br>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="email" class="form-control" style="width: 200px;"> <!-- Add Google Button Here --> <br><br>
                                <input type="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control" style="width: 200px;"> <!-- Add Twitter Button Here --><br><br>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button><br><br>
                                <a data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" href="#signin" >Already a member ? Sign In</a>
                            </form>
                            <div class="pull-right">


                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
                        <a data-toggle="modal" href="#signin" >Already a member ? Sign In</a> -->
                        </div>
                        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
                    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                    </div><!-- /.modal -->
              <!-- sign up modal finish -->
```

This has resolved my issue now.